# How to get movie details from Amazon API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, rest, amazon-web-services

How can I get movie details from Amazon API ("Product Advertising API"?) using JavaScript, $.ajax(), and RESTfull calls?

Example: I'd like to get the reviews & # of people who reviewed any given movie, e.g., 4.6 out of 5 rating for movie Valentines Day, from 3,450 users who rated it.

1. How do I search for movies given a title
2. How do I just provide an "amazon movie id" and get the details from that?

Answer (score 1):

You can only call the API directly from client side if the Amazon API supports JSON-P encoded replies.

If they do, you simply set up an Ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
 url : "the url";
 dataType : jsonp
 success : function(data){}
});
```

If they do not support JSON-P, you will have to make the ajax request to your own server side script, which will then make a cURL request to the API, get the data and pass it back to your client side code.

Comment: thanks xbonez. I'm actually looking to see if anyone has actually done this, using the amazon api before.